# Can't connect to a port of pod which running an android emulator in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, android-emulator

I'm running a deploy in a k8s cluster.
The deploy runs an android emulator image which expose port `5555` for adb connect.
I'm trying to connect to this port from another pod in the cluster.

The problem is that the port 5555 seems inaccessible from other pods.

There're 2 containers running in this port. Apart from the emulator, there's another container which exposes port `8000`, and this port can be accessed.

More information:
The pod's ip is `172.30.113.239`.

1. curl `172.30.113.239:5555` from aother pod in this cluster : connection refused.
2. curl `172.30.113.239:8000` from aother pod in this cluster : connect success.
3. curl `172.30.113.239:5555` from THIS pod : connection refused.
4. curl `172.30.113.239:8000` from THIS pod : connect success.
5. curl `localhost:5555` from THIS pod : connect success.
6. curl `localhost:8000` from THIS pod: connect success.

This is really strange to me since I didn't see any difference between the port `5555` and `8888`,  any idea what may cause this problem?

---

Here is a brief of the deployment file.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    service: android-emulator
  name: android-emulator
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: android-emulator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: android-emulator
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - cd /opt/android-sdk-linux;emulator -avd avd30 -no-window  -memory 4096 -cores
          4;sleep 99999
        env:
        - name: resources
          value: 4c4Gig8Gis
        image: test/android30:v1.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: android-emulator
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5555
          protocol: TCP     
      - env:
        - name: resources
          value: 2c4Gig8Gis
        - name: serviceName
          value: scrcpy
        image: test/scrcpy-web:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: testtest-android-emulator-scrcpy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          protocol: TCP
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

---

Edit2:

The image I'm using is from this repo `https://github.com/docker-android-sdk/android-30`, it's an modified version of android emulator.
I think this is more an docker image issue rather than k8s, as suggested by @Dolphin. I'm still trying to figure out how to configure the address bind.

Comment: it seems you should bind you servcice to 0.0.0.0? Because you could connection from localhost but not work for ip.

Comment: @Dolphin I think you're right, this seems to be more of a image issue rather than a k8s issue... I think I should check how the image bind the port. The image use the official android emulator image, and I'm still investigating.

Comment: @mosakashaka In this [official AAOS doc](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/avd/cloud_emulator#setup-emulator-service) they have mentioned how to deploy android emulator with external IP. you can set a static IP to your pod and run the commands mentioned in the URL using the kubernetes manifest file or helm chart in your case.

Comment: @Kranthiveer thanks I saw that, but that kind of only work with docker, in cluster pod don't have a fixed ip address,, and I'm not sure what's the external and internal ip here in case of k8s pod.

Comment: @mosakashaka you can use calico CNI plugin for [assigning static IP address to a kubernetes pod](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/networking/ipam/use-specific-ip) and then by following the AAOS documentation you can expose your android emulator to the pod's IP.

Comment: @mosakashaka there is one more way, you can fetch the IP address of the pod by running `ifconfig` or `ip a` command and store the IP address value in an environment variable and pass that variable while binding the service or like `Dolphin` said try binding to `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: @mosakashaka have you gone through my response, kindly revert back if you are still facing some issues..

Comment: @Kranthiveer I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue mainly occurs when you forgot to do port-forwarding or exposing your service in kubernetes as explained in the [official kubernetes document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/). They have explained each step for deploying and exposing your application ports, so that they can be accessed within the cluster.

In the above doc they have used mongoDB as an example for demonstrating the port-forwarding. In your case you need to select the android emulator port and expose it using the port forwarding. You can use the below command to perform port-forwarding in kubernetes

> ```
> kubectl port-forward <name of the pod> 5555:5000
> ```

As per this [official Android Emulator Container scripts documentation](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts) the ADB container port seems to be getting bound to the localhost. Try binding it to the pod's IP and then do the port forwarding, this will expose your ADB port to other pods in the cluster.

Comment: I think port forward is needed only when I need to access the port outside the cluster, right?  But currently I'm trying to connect to this port from inside the cluster. Also, the port `8000` in the same pod can be accessed, so I don't think port forward is the issue heere..

Comment: `the ADB container port seems to be getting bound to the localhost`, this seems may cause the problem. Do you have idea how can I change the binding ? I'll check the document right away to see if there's any configuration about it.

Comment: kubectl port-forward is a command that enables you to create a secure tunnel between your local computer and a Pod running in a Kubernetes cluster. This allows you to access the application running in the Pod as though it were running locally on your computer. (**source:** [kodekloud](https://kodekloud.com/blog/port-forwarding-kubernetes/#:~:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20get%20started!-,What%20Is%20Kubectl%2DPort%2DForward%20%26%20Why%20Do%20We%20Use%20It%20in%20Kubernetes%3F,-kubectl%20port%2Dforward))

Comment: @mosakashaka Seems the port forwarding issue is only with this particular container port, can you try this by applying port-forwarding command given above or create a service of type **cluster IP** and expose your application internally, you can also use [**kubernetes network policies**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) for managing the accessibility of your container.

Comment: @mosakashaka can you also provide your manifest files so that we can go through it and suggest any changes that are required.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to connect to the `5555` port of this pod (by its inner ip) from another pod in the same cluster, not from outside the cluster. I'm not from my computer or outside this cluster.

Comment: I run this application by a local helm chart, I can provide the deployment YAML file , I'm not sure if that's the `manifest files`?

Comment: Hi, I've append the deployment file in the original question, the image is from our inner repo, so that's not accessible from internet.

Comment: @mosakashaka Yes can you provide those helm charts and you can replace any critical information.

Comment: @mosakashaka In this [official AAOS doc](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/avd/cloud_emulator#setup-emulator-service) they have mentioned how to deploy android emulator with external IP. you can set a static IP to your pod and run the commands mentioned in the URL using the kubernetes manifest file or helm chart in your case.